# want a confirmation box, if you want to delete the data using jsp and java script

Tags: javascript, jsp

I tried something but not getting anything..
while I click the remove link I have to get a confirmation box but I am not getting it..
can anybody suggest me ?

JSP

```
urlencrypt:url value="abc.action" htmlEscape="true" var="removeLink"/>
<td><a href="removeLink"  onclick="confirmRemoveQuestion('${removeLink}')">
<fmt:message key="link.remove" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var confirmRemoveDialog;
var confirmOkUrl=  ; 

function setRemoveQuestionDialog()
{
    var handleYes = function() { 
        window.location = confirmOkUrl;
        this.hide(); 
    };

    var handleNo = function() { 
        this.hide();
    };

    var confDialogButtons = [ { text:"<fmt:message key="link.cancel"/>", handler:handleNo, isDefault:true}, 
                                { text:"<fmt:message key="link.ok"/>",handler:handleYes } 
                              ];

    confirmRemoveDialog = getConfirmOKDialog(confDialogButtons);
}

function confirmRemoveQuestion(url)
{
    confirmOkUrl = url;
    setRemoveQuestionDialog();
    showConfirmDialog(confirmRemoveDialog, "<fmt:message key="removeLink.confirmMessage"/>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is before the response, How does the html and javascript of this look like in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

Use following simple code

```
<script>
function confirmRemoveQuestion(link){
    if(show_confirm()){
     window.location = link;
     this.hide(); 
    }
    else{
     this.hide();  
    }
}
function show_confirm()
{
  return confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
}
</script>

<td><a href="#"  onclick="confirmRemoveQuestion('${removeLink}')"> <!--removLink-->
<fmt:message key="link.remove" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that

```
showConfirmDialog(confirmRemoveDialog, "<fmt:message key="removeLink.confirmMessage"/>");
```

is syntactically incorrect? Debugging would show you this.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant : `"<fmt:message key=" + removeLink.confirmMessage + "/>"`